# Constructing a rotation matrix from complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, geometry, matrices

I am trying to construct a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ rotating around an axis $\hat{n}$ in a basis $\{\hat{n},\hat{u}_{1},\hat{u}_{2}\}$. Formally:

> Given a basis $\{\hat{n},\hat{u}_{1},\hat{u}_{2}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, we have a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ with eigenvalue $1$ and corresponding eigenvector $\hat{n}$. Can we explicitly construct $\mathbf{R}$ from this information?

As $\mathbf{R}\in \mathrm{SO}(3)$ we know its three eigenvalues: $$\lambda_{1}=1,\, \lambda_{2}=e^{-i\varphi},\, \lambda_{3}=e^{i\varphi}$$

Where $\varphi\in\mathbb{R}$ is the rotation angle. Diagonalizing $\mathbf{R}$ we get $\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}^{T}$. As we are working in the specified basis we have $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{I}_{3\times3}$ as there is no change in basis. However, this gives us:

$$\mathbf{R}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{-i\varphi} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{i\varphi}\end{pmatrix}$$

However, this is not a real matrix, and thus does not meet our requirement. How can we get from this matrix to the matrix we would expect, i.e.: $$\mathbf{R}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(\varphi) & -\sin(\varphi) \\
0 & \sin(\varphi) & \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonalized form has complex conjugate eigenvectors. The most natural way to get a real basis from them is to take the real part and the imaginary part of one of them as a new basis. This basis will give you the final result you desire!

Edit:Consider a positive rotation of $\pi/2$ about the z-axis. The eigenvectors are (0,0,1), (1,i,0), and (1,-i,0), with eigenvectors 1,i, and -i, respectively. The real part of the last two vectors is (0,1,0), and the imaginary part is (0,0,1). In this basis, the rotation matrix has the desired form. This does not work for..angle of 180.

The transition matrix from the complex basis to the real basis is 
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1/2 & -1/2 \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean? What would the new basis consist of?